# Copying data to new table in a specific fashion

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table looking like this:

```
ID USER ITEM QTY
1  A    I1   AI1
2  A    I2   AI2
3  A    I3   AI3
4  B    I1   BI1
5  B    I2   BI2
6  B    I3   BI3
7  C    I1   CI1
      ...
```

I have created a new table, but would like to copy the values in like so:

```
USER  I1    I2    I3
A     AI1   AI2   AI3
B     BI1   BI2   BI3
C     CI1   CI2   CI3
           ...
```

How could I go about doing this using SQL in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregate` to do this

```
select USER,
       max(case when ITEM='I1' then QTY END) As I1,
       max(case when ITEM='I2' then QTY END) as I2,
       max(case when ITEM='I3' then QTY END) as I3
from yourtable
group by USER
```